# KeyDown KeyPress Conundrum - How to cancel the Space in Ctrl + Space

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

If I understand correctly, the KeyDown event cannot stop a character key (space) from being passed to a control.

But the KeyPress event doesn't tell me whether the Ctrl is down.

But I only need to cancel the space if the Ctrl is down.

How can I prevent an edit control from receiving the space keypress if the ctrl is also down?

Purpose: I have a text box, from which I am making search suggestions. I want to pop the suggestions up using the short cut ctrl+space. But in this case, I don't want to add the space to the edit text.

Comment: This has all the markings of an XY question. If you tell us why you are asking I bet you'll get better help.

Comment: An XY question?   I have a text box, for which I am making search suggestions.  I want to pop the suggestions up using the short cut ctrl+space.  But in this case, I don't want to add the space to the edit text as part for the search.

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry.  When I know what I am trying to do, I thought I was being totally clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the KeyPress event doesn't tell me whether the Ctrl is down.

No, but you can use the Win32 [`GetKeyState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) function instead.

> How can I prevent an edit control from receiving the space keypress if the ctrl is also down?

Like this:

```
procedure TForm58.Edit1KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if (Key = ' ') and (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0) then
  begin
    Key := #0;
    // do something...
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a text box, from which I am making search suggestions. I want to pop the suggestions up using the short cut ctrl+space. But in this case, I don't want to add the space to the edit text.

Handle the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> input with a shortcut attached to an action, for instance. Handled that way the key will not reach the edit control.

Comment: I haven't really used an action list.  This search box is wrapped up in a frame, and this frame will be used many times on a given form.  Will the actionlists conflict with each other, or will the keystroke be captured by the frame that I am on and not propagate to the other instances of this actionlist?